# Boolean output with comparison operator

Tags: c, boolean-operations

Why the output of the following C code is 1 (True)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a, b = 1, c = 3, d = 2;
    a = b < c < d;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

While the same expression gives "False" in python.

Comment: Condition operators returns always either `TURE` or `FALSE` depending on the condition check.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see the topic [Should i use tags in title?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the order of evaluation from left to right.

`b<c` is true so it returns 1.

Then

`1<d` Yes so you get 1

So

`a=1`

Make sure since you are using relational operators the value returned will be true or false. i.e 0 or 1

Answer (score 2):

Statement

```
a=b<c<d;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = ( b < c ) < d;
```

It is not the same as

```
a = ( b < c ) && ( c < d );
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.107) The result has
>   type int.

So in this statement

```
a = ( b < c ) < d;
```

as b is less than c then the result of subexpression ( b < c ) will be equal to 1 according to the quote of the Standard. And 1 is less than d that is equal to 2. So the overall result is 1.

Answer (score -2):

```
a = ( b < c && c < d)
```

should return the value that you want.

Comment: the answer you provided is no way related to the question.

Comment: @Madan, it does, in some way (though it doesn't explicitly answer the question). Btw. try to focus on being precise by yourself! Where in the OP's code or question did you see conditional operator ? And it's certainly `TRUE`, not `TURE`.

Comment: this is an answer to the real question. OP wants to know why its code is not working like he thinks, AND how to make it works